# SQL Server : KEY lock prevents FK on nearby row, but not SELECT

Tags: sql-server, locking, transaction

I have the following table structure (simplified, pseudocode):

```
TABLE dbo.Users (Id int NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY)
TABLE dbo.Transfers (
    Id int NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    CreatedByUserId NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.Users (Id)
    ... -- no other user-related fields
)
```

I have the following situation in application code:

```
-- Given a User with Id 5 that already exists
BeginTransaction
1. INSERT INTO dbo.Users (...) VALUES (...) -- Creates user with Id 6
    NotInTransaction.Start
    2. INSERT dbo.Transfers (CreatedByUserId, ...)  VALUES (5, ...)
    NotInTransaction.End
...
CommitTransaction
```

In this specific case (when existing user and newly created user have nearby Ids), I get a timeout from step 2.

Now the interesting part is that I paused the application on step 2, and tried the following things outside the (paused) transaction:

- `SELECT * FROM dbo.Users WHERE UserId = @UserId`
  works (not locked) for **all** values of `@UserId` except 6, which makes total sense
- `INSERT dbo.Transfers (CreatedByUserId, ...)  VALUES (@UserId, ...)`
  works for `1,2,3,4`, locked for `6` and `5`

I did a quick look on `sys.dm_tran_locks` (which I am not a master of) with some `hobt` joins, and when `INSERT` is locked, it shows

```
ObjectName | resource_type | resource_description | resource_associated_entity_id | request_mode | request_status
Users      | KEY           | (b9b173bbe8d5)       | 72057594047299584             | X            | GRANT
Users      | KEY           | (b9b173bbe8d5)       | 72057594047299584             | S            | WAIT
```

Now, the question is: why can I select user `5` from outside the transaction, but not insert into a table that references it through `FK`?

Comment: UPDATE:  
For some reason today I can not reproduce the issue in the exact same way as described in the question. I was able to reproduce (and fix) a different situation altogether, where the problem was caused by a ninja update to a row by the legacy code. I will attempt to delete the question to avoid misleading people.

Comment: I'm closing as too localized instead of deleting.  We can delete down the road if we need.

Answer (score 3):

Your simplified repro simplified the problem beyond the point it repro...

```
create TABLE dbo.Users (Id int NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY)

create TABLE dbo.Transfers (
    Id int NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    CreatedByUserId int NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.Users (Id))

insert into Users default values;
go 5

insert into transfers (CreatedByUserId) values (1), (2), (3), (4);
go

begin tran
insert into Users default values;
insert into transfers (CreatedByUserId) values (6);

-- from separate connection
insert into transfers (CreatedByUserId) values (5);
```

Since the problem no longer reproes it means your simplified out a critical piece of information. Your symptoms look suspiciously similar to serializable isolation level issues. Perhaps you're using the [harmful default `TransactionScope` constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/dbrowne/using-new-transactionscope-considered-harmful)?

Comment: You are right, though I can't provide complete version either, as it some legacy C# code that a) I can not share b) does hundreds of lines of of unrelated stuff. But the idea to reproduce it in similar situation is good, I will try it. My current theory is actually key hash collision, which may explain why it is hard to reproduce (depends on what is included in hash, need to research that).

Comment: `select %%lockres%%, count(*) from <table> group by %%lockres%%` does it find any duplicates?

Comment: For some reason today I can not reproduce the issue in the exact same way as described in the question. I was able to reproduce (and fix) a different situation altogether, where the problem was caused by a ninja update to a row by the legacy code. I will delete the question to avoid misleading people.